# foforEach(function(el) как записать правилно

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

собсвенно как записать сюда url учитывая el в пути к странице 1-2-3...

```
function picdown(num) {
[1,2,3,4,5,6].forEach(function(el) { 
if (el === num) { 
            var msg = $('.pic' + el).serialize(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url:'/ajax/pic1.html' ,
            data: msg, 
            success: function(data) { 
            $('.pic' + el).html(data);  
            }, 
            error: function(xhr, str){ 
            alert('ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode); 
            } 
        }); 

}  
}); 
}
jQuery('.cp1').click(function() {picdown(1)});
jQuery('.cp2').click(function() {picdown(2)});
jQuery('.cp3').click(function() {picdown(3)});
jQuery('.cp4').click(function() {picdown(4)});
jQuery('.cp5').click(function() {picdown(5)});
jQuery('.cp6').click(function() {picdown(6)});
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте мыслить не для  каждого конкретного случая, а обобщенно. Действия у вас однотипны. Есть 6 элементов, и вы пишите 6 строк для навешивая обработчиков.  Далее в цикле вы для 6 элементов сверяете номер.
Задайтесь вопросом, можно ли сделать это в одной функции? Наверное ведь можно, если начальный элемент будет хранить сведения об индексе?

```
<a href="#" class="cp cp1" data-idx="1">
<a href="#" class="cp cp2" data-idx="2">
```

Ок, теперь к общему классу `cp` повесьте единый обработчик, который извлечет `data-idx` для элемента:

```
 $(".cp").click(function(){
       var idx = $(this).data('idx');
       var $p   = $(".pic" + idx);

       $p.load("/ajax/pic" + idx + ".html", $p.serialize() );
 });
```

Comment: _можете так же воспользоваться вариантом с_ - чем?:)

Comment: Спасибо все работает

Comment: @Grundy :D сначала был `$.post`, и хотел дописать про `$.load` :)